# Avoid Reading Huge User Submitted Form Data in Server's Memory until signaled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET application. In this application I have a page where user can submit a lot of data to server. But sometime I just need to just check some request header and may reject the request completely. In these cases I don't want my Server memory to hold the huge user submitted data unnecessary for a period of time. Is there is any way in ASP.NET to not hold any user submitted data until I signal after reading the header.

Comment: No, because the server reads this when it first gets the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all sent with the request. To do what you want, you would need two requests, since the whole "until I signal" implies a server response and another client request.

Depending on what you're trying to check, you *could* do a two-stage request, making the client submit a simple request first, obtain some authorization code to submit the larger request, and then sending that authorization code along with the larger request. That's essentially how authorization works in most Web APIs, but it all depends on the client conforming to specifications.

In a documented API, that shouldn't be a problem, because the client will understand that unless they follow procedure, they won't be able to interact with the API. It's a bigger problem for a generic website, where the browser itself isn't capable of handling this properly and the end-user probably wouldn't cooperate even if it was.

However, even in an API environment, you'll still get large unauthorized requests from non-conforming clients. They'll be blocked, but your server still has to process it to block, which kind of defeats the purpose of blocking it. You might as well just go ahead and finish it at that point, instead of incurring additional requests, including a repeat of the large request when it's sent with proper authorization.

Long and short, it just doesn't really make sense to try to stop it. Your best bet would be to simply break up the form or whatever into multiple steps so that the individual posted steps are not that large, and if there is some issue, you can stop it at the first smaller request.

Comment: I have found that I can do 100 Expect Continue. But not know how to implement.

Comment: Expect Continue is handled at the level of IIS. I've seen something about using a subclass of IHttpModule to handle Expect Continue in code, but I'm not sure exactly how you'd go about doing that.